# Understanding the sentence meaning

Tags: american-english, sentence

I am working on one project, where I have been offered this:

> Royalty of 15% on net revenue of the product. As a good will gesture,
>   we will also pay you an advance against future royalties, during the
>   writing stage. This advance will be USD $1500.

Is royalty is my share in product? Also what they mean by `advance against future royalties`

Answer (score 1):

[Royalty:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/royalty)

> - A share in the proceeds paid to an inventor or a proprietor for the right to use his or her invention or services. (AHD)

- 15% out of total revenues will be payed   as royalties. Plus 1500 USD will  paid soon as an advance of future royalties,  (this amount will be deducted later from future royalties).

Comment: thanks, but I am still not clear with `advance of future royalties` does it mean `deducting 1500 USD` from my future earning ?

Comment: Yes, they are saying that they are  "advancing" 1.500 USD as a good will gesture "against" future royalties.

Comment: @user123 It means that they'll give you $1.5K right now, and you won't get any more money from them until the product returns more than $10K in net revenue.